# CSS - Sidebar not floating right of content

Tags: html, css, styles, sidebar

I would like the ***sidebar*** div to fit nicely beside the ***main*** div and I have done this multiple times before... I have no idea why it is not working this time and need a fresh pair of eyes to help me work out the problem.

Here is the full HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>SiteName | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

    <body>
        <div id="screen">
            <div id="header">
            <img style="float:left;" src="C:\Users\Jack\Downloads\Images\GFX\Website\awesomeface.jpg" width="75px" height="75px">
                <div id="title">
                    <h1>SiteName</h1>
                </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Terms of Use</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <div id="body">
                <h2>Welcome to the new website!</h2>
                <p class="bindent">For Chryses sought with costly gifts to gain His captive daughter from the victor's chain. Suppliant the venerable father stands; Apollo's awful ensigns grace his hands By these he begs; and lowly bending down, Extends the sceptre and the laurel crown He sued to all, but chief implored for grace The brother-kings, of Atreus' royal race</p>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <h3>News</h3>
                <p class="sindent">Declare, O Muse! in what ill-fated hour Sprung the fierce strife, from what offended power Latona's son a dire contagion spread, And heap'd the camp with mountains of the dead; The king of men his reverent priest defied, And for the king's offence the people died.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Here is the full CSS:

```
#screen {
color: white;
font-family: verdana;
}

#header {
background: black;
border: 8px solid darkred;
padding: 1em;
}

#title {
text-indent: 5em;
}

#body {
padding: 1em;
border: 8px solid darkred;
background:#3d594b;
}

#sidebar {
padding: 1em;
border: 8px solid darkred;
background:#3d594b;
float: right;
}

#footer {
}

ul
{
position:relative;
float: left;
left: 50%;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

li
{
float:left;
position:relative;
right:50%;
}

a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
width:200px;
color:white;
background-color:darkred;
text-align:center;
padding:0.75em;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:lime;
}

.sindent {
text-indent:1em;
}

.bindent {
text-indent:2em;
}
```

As you can see I'm not clearing anything in the ***main*** div yet the ***sidebar*** div isn't floating right.

Thanks for your time, in advance.

EDIT:
The width's I added were just to see if it would float and it still didn't.

EDIT 2:
Added full CSS and HTML.

Comment: post the html here also. we need to reproduce the problem

Comment: Could also add a fiddle www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: where is your `#main` id in that html?

Comment: It was originally called ***body*** sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the sidebar before main in the html, it should work just fine.  The problem is that main, since it isn't floating, takes up space in the document and thus the sidebar starts below the main.  There are other ways to do this as well if you want to keep the order in the html the same, but putting the sidebar first is probably simplest.

try http://jsfiddle.net/mZfK9/

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <h3>News</h3>
    <p class="sindent">Declare, O Muse! in what ill-fated hour Sprung the fierce strife, from what offended power Latona's son a dire contagion spread, And heap'd the camp with mountains of the dead; The king of men his reverent priest defied, And for the king's offence the people died.</p>
</div><div id="body">
    <h2>Welcome to the new website!</h2>
    <p class="bindent">For Chryses sought with costly gifts to gain His captive daughter from the victor's chain. Suppliant the venerable father stands; Apollo's awful ensigns grace his hands By these he begs; and lowly bending down, Extends the sceptre and the laurel crown He sued to all, but chief implored for grace The brother-kings, of Atreus' royal race</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am trying to get it to float without the widths, thank you though!

Comment: If you don't constrain something, then both div's will default to 100% width.  Traditionally, people want to constrain the sidebar to either something like 15em or 25% or some combination of that.  See http://jsfiddle.net/FdBEx/ for a possible solution.  Note that I did put overflow: hidden; on #main as well as width: 15em; on #sidebar

Comment: Your initial answer basically answered my question, and your comment confirmed it. Your answer was clear and easy to understand, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A div is a block-level element by default and will occupy the full width of the browser.

You could give the main-div `display: inline-block` or float it, `float: left`.

Comment: Adding display: inline-block had no effect and float was weird, please: http://jsfiddle.net/bgytc/

Comment: You need to add `display: inline-block` to #body.

Comment: I don't know what to tell ya, it works for me. Perhaps post an updated fiddle.

Comment: That page, and the revisions you have made to your original question, are much more detailed. I answered the question that you originally asked, but it is now a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the width to body as well as to sidebar otherwise they will always be 100% and will come in different rows

http://jsfiddle.net/fUMHF/

```
#body {
padding: 1em;
border: 8px solid darkred;
background:#3d594b;
    width:60%;
    float:left;

}

#sidebar {

padding: 1em;
border: 8px solid darkred;
background:#3d594b;
float: right;
    width:20%;
}
```

Comment: Oh so to have the sidebar floating to the right of the main I need to have specified widths?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `float: left;` for the main and sidebar

This solves the problem. Then use `clear: both;` for the footer